# What is R's equivalent of the following Stata commands?

Tags: r, statistics, stata

I recently came across the following Stata commands and I would like to convert that to R using `lm` and `lmer`. But I do not fully grasp the syntax of Stata at all, so I do not know how to convert the following Stata commands into `lm` / `lmer` in R.

1. `xtreg y x1, i(x2) fe`
2. `xtreg y x1, i(x2) re`

Did a bit of research from the internet, (1) computes the within only effects. And `xtreg` is for random intercept model. So I am guessing both (1) and (2) would translate to `lmer` functions. Is this the same as below ?

1. `xtreg y x1, i(x2) fe` = **fixed effects of**  `lmer(y ~ x1 + (1|x2), data = some_data)` ?
2. `xtreg y x1, i(x2) re` = **random effects of**  `lmer(y ~ x1 + (1|x2), data = some_data)` ?

Is `i(x2)` being specified as the random effects above ?

However, looking at the [guide here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtreg.pdf), the model formula is as below, i.e. observations are transformed by subtracting the group means and adding the grand. And the formula looks like standard regression to me. Yet other resources are saying xtreg is for random intercept model. I am getting really confused now. Should it be a random intercept model or standard regression model ? And do I have to transform the `y` and `x` by subtracting the group means and adding backing the grand means ?

[image]

Comment: Not knowing Stata doesn't rule out consultation of https://www.stata.com/manuals/xtxtreg.pdf  (The usual Google points to the entry in the manuals for Stata 13, whereas that link points to the latest version at the time of writing Stata 16.1.)(

Comment: I read that but it didn't help me to convert the Stata commands to R. This is why I am asking the question here. If I did not do any digging at all, then why would I come up with the `lmer` code above ? I was looking for people to tell me whether my `lmer` code is equivalent to the Stata command. @NickCox

Comment: I was not accusing you of doing no research.  If you understood and explained what the `xtreg` commands were doing then that could help others understand what should be the correct translation to R, and the extra explanation would do no harm. Or, the documentation link could help the same others you're asking for help who might not know Stata.  In reverse, if you said to me, as someone quite familiar with Stata, what is the equivalent in Stata of `xyzab` in R I might not know, but if you explained what `xyzab` does statistically or gave a link to documentation I would be more likely to know.

Comment: (I didn't downvote, or vote to close, but those actions were intended by others as some kind of signal, I guess. Hard to know who's right if comments on how to improve a question are likely to be misread.)

Comment: Thank you. I elaborated my question.  Hope it makes sense to the community where my confusion is coming from.

Comment: This question might be better suited for stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the `plm` package - it is designed to estimate all different types of panel linear models.

That said, you could do the same as above with

```
## fixed effect model
lm(y ~ x1 + as.factor(x2), data=some_data)

## random effect model
lmer(y ~ x1 + (1|x2), data=some_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my research I see xtreg can be used to fit a number of different mixed or non-mixed models, including the random intercept model.

`xtreg y x1, i(x2) fe` should fit a fixed effects model where the subject-specific effects are averaged out and the resulting marginal model has population averaged effects for your covariates. This is the same as fitting a regular regression model with the subject or cluster identifier used as a covariate (the post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82352/multi-level-model-with-varying-intercept-vs-fixed-effect-regression) provides more detail).